# Removing ceramic tile (non-asbestos) on top of subfloor and some black mastic (asbestos)

Tags: floor, mastic

In middle of 1/2 bath remodel in 1970 home.  Prev owner had remodeled bathroom 10+ yrs ago.  That contractor left orig vanity in place but cut and removed vinyl tiles around vanity and laid ceramic tiles in thinset on subfloor.  I pulled the vanity and had the original vinyl tiles and mastic tested.  Tiles:neg.  Mastic: positive (3%).  I want to pull up all of the newer tiles and leave the rectangle of orig tiles in place.
Question: do I need to bring in an abatement co to remove the non-asbestos ceramic tile or can I diy (as long as I leave original tile alone)

1st pic show rectangle of original tile.  2nd shows underneath a few ceramic (non asbestos) tiles I pulled next to this rectangle.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on local rules. As an example here, the [local rules for homeowners](https://pscleanair.gov/192/Homeowner-Renovation) let you do your own removal so long as you file a permit, pay a fee, and follow specific disposal processes. Most of the time people elect to just encapsulate and leave the asbestos in place, as it's less work and cheaper to do things that way. Check with your local building department where you got your permit. They will know where to send you.